# Xpath: how to select a descendant regardless any ancestor?

Tags: xpath

Is this valid ?

```
//p//div/a
```

Expected to match `a` regardless any element between p and div, like in:

```
//p/span/div/a

//p/strong/span/i/div/a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use: `//p//div/a`. This will match p appearing anywhere and `div/a` appearing at any level (i.e., descendent) under `p`.

I see you have edited your question to match my answer, so now the answer is yes!